# Eloquent boolean property sometimes gets updated, sometimes it does not

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following mutator on my model:

```
/**
 * @param $value
 */
public function setBreadcrumbAttribute($value)
{
    $fix = is_null($value) ? 0 : (integer) $value;
    $this->attributes['breadcrumb'] = $fix;
}
```

And the following in my html:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('breadcrumb', 1, null, [
    'id' => 'breadcrumb'
]) !!}
```

And this is in my controller:

```
$page->update($request->only('title', 'body', 'breadcrumb'));
```

The breadcrumb property gets updated about 6 / 10 times of saving the form. The rest, it seems to be setting the correct property `$this->attributes['breadcrumb']` but is not saving to the database for some reason.

This is driving me crazy.

P.S. The reason why I have `is_null` check is because if I deselect the checkbox, it return `null` to the request.

P.P.S. `breadcrumb` property is saved as `boolean (tinyint)` in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes don't get passed at all if they are not checked. So its not in the input when unchecked. You should either check for this before filling the model, or adding a default to the form.

You can add a hidden field with a value of 0 and the same name as the checkbox before your checkbox in the html. Inputs are passed in order, so when it is checked it will override the hidden input. When it isn't checked, the hidden one will be the one you end up with. So either way you will end up with a value in your request input.

Comment: I used that trick as well, following this link: http://nielson.io/2014/02/handling-checkbox-input-in-laravel/ which is exactly what you recommended, but I still have the issue of the model sometimes not being saved. It updates all the other properties except this one. And it happens about 3 / 10 times.. It is very odd!